# Where are Eclipse Bookmarks stored?

Tags: eclipse

Does anyone know where bookmarks are stored in the Eclipse IDE?

I had to delete a Java project from my workspace, then use the Import Existing project option to reset some configuration settings, and now my bookmarks are gone.  I'm trying to understand how this affected my bookmarks, since everything on the file system except for the Eclipse .project and .classpath files should have remained unchanged.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Generally they are located in

```
{workspace}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/{project}/.markers
```

removing the project from the workspace would have removed the markers as well.

Comment: mine was sotred in {workspace}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/{project_name}/.markers, Eclipse 3.4.1

Comment: be aware that bookmarks and markers located in the same .markers file!

Answer (score 0):

File to store bookmarks(markers) is not human readable. In case task to preserve your bookmarks between workspaces just select all bookmarks in Bookmark view and copy all.

Comment: At least in Eclipse Photon release, drag and drop or copy-paste doesn't seem to work directly. can you elaborate more?

Comment: Related Eclipse bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=357062